# Check if a given multiple file exist

Tags: c++, ifstream

I'm new to C++. Got stuck in a portion of an existing code base, where I need to identify whether two files exist or not. If any of these are existing or both, we need to set a flag.

The snippet looks like:

```
bool Flag = false;
string string_one, string_two;
string_one = "/blah/blah/bhah1.ext";
string_two = "/blah/blah/bhah2.ext";

std::ifstream fs1( string_one.c_str() );
if ( (bool)fs1 ==  false )
  Flag = true;

std::ifstream fs2( string_two.c_str() );
if ( (bool)fs2 == false )
  Flag = true;
```

Now, the issue is:

if `string_one` is an existing file, the first `if` is working fine and value of Flag is not getting changed(still `false`). But if `string_two` is also existing, somehow the value of `Flag` is getting set to `true`. Ran debugger and have found that control is going inside `if ( (bool)fs2 == false )` at last.

Is it because of using `std::ifstream` twice?

I maybe asking a silly question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: using ifstream twice shouldn't be a problem as they are different streams (fs1 and fs2).

Comment: I'm confused. Flag should *not* be set to false if the first file exists.

Comment: You only ever set `Flag` to `true`, except at initialization. So if either file exists, `Flag` will be `true`. You never set `Flag` to `false` in any `if`, contrary to your statement that *"the first if is working fine and Flag is set to false"*

Comment: I suspect something has changed during your retyping. Use copy and paste. (And by the way: `bool Flag = !fs1 || !fs2;` is much easier on the eyes.)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux:  **the first if is working fine and Flag is set to false**: I mean the value of `Flag` is not changed.

Comment: Don't call your variables `Flag`. It's hugely uninformative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your post, you say that you want to set the flag if either (or both) file exists. Your current code sets the flag if they do not exist (they can't be opened for reading). Try something like this:

```
bool flag = false;

std::string string_one = "/blah/blah/bhah1.ext";
std::string string_two = "/blah/blah/bhah2.ext";

std::ifstream fs1(string_one.c_str());
std::ifstream fs2(string_two.c_str());

if (fs1 || fs2) {
  flag = true;
}
```

This will set `flag` to `true` if either one is successfully opened for reading. If you would like to set the flag if either DO NOT exist, simply negate the expression in the `if` statement. You could also do the following (as mentioned above in a comment on your question):

```
flag = !fs1 || !fs2;
```

Comment: Thanks! If **I want to set the flag if either (or both) files does not exist**, then is it going to work?

`if ( !fs1 || !fs2 )`

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler is C++17 compatible, you should use the [`<filesystem>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) Library.

```
bool Flag = false;
string string_one = "/blah/blah/bhah1.ext";
string string_two = "/blah/blah/bhah2.ext";
//MSVC
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
//GCC or any other compiler which has moved filesystem out of the experimental namespace
//namespace fs = std::filesystem;
Flag = fs::exists(string_one) || fs::exists(string_two);
```

This code doesn't require you to actually *open* the files, which may be good for performance reasons.